# Find the solution to $\frac{dy}{dx}=\left(\frac{-y}{x}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}$ that goes through the point $(8,1)$.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Find the solution to $\frac{dy}{dx}=\left(\frac{-y}{x}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}$ that goes through the point $(8,1)$.

The answer is $x^\frac{2}{3} + y^\frac{2}{3}=5$ but I do not understand how to get there so any help is appreciated thanks!

Comment: What methods do you know? This is known as a 'separable' equation. Does that word mean anything to you?

Comment: This is separable ODE. I suggest looking on the internet first then ask here. It is not so difficult concept given you already take calculus.

Comment: @Blueteal Are you in the middle of a calculus class?  Is this problem taken from the corresponding textbook?  If so, what tools are in the corresponding pages of the book shortly before the problem is presented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$
\frac{\mathsf dy}{\mathsf dx} = \left(\frac{-y}x\right)^{\frac13} = (-1)^{\frac13}\left(\frac yx\right)^{\frac13} = - \left(\frac yx\right)^{\frac13} \implies y^{-\frac13}\ \mathsf dy = -\left(\frac 1x\right)^{\frac13}\ \mathsf dx
$$
and so integrating yields
$$
\int y^{-\frac13}\ \mathsf dy = \int-\left(\frac 1x\right)^{\frac13}\ \mathsf dx \implies \frac 32 y^{\frac23} = -\frac32 x^{\frac 23} + C,
$$
or
$y^{\frac 23} + x^{\frac 23}= C$. The condition that $y(8)=1$ gives
$$
8^{\frac23} + 1^{\frac23} = C \implies 4+1 = C \implies C = 5,
$$
and hence the solution is
$$
x^{\frac23}+y^{\frac23} = 5.
$$